# Reading a Windows-1252 file in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using node to read a text document using readFile and within that document is a character

```
�
```

This is a windows-1252 character but it is being converted in javascript to utf-8 automatically. The correct character should actually display as `Å`.

Is there a way I can convert this character from utf-8 to windows-1252 to render the correct character?

The file is being read using nodes readFile method and is being read as utf-8, due to the lack of support for the necessary encoding.

```
fs.readFile(`${logDirectory}myText.txt`,"utf-8", (err, text) => { ... }
```

I've tried a few options such as iconv-lite and legacy-decode but neither seem to return the correct result.

Any guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try reading the file with the `latin1`-encoding as `Windows-1252` is based on that:

```
fs.readFile(`${logDirectory}myText.txt`,'latin1', (err, text) => { ... }
```

Also note that in NodeJS the utf-8 encoding is called `utf8` instead of `utf-8` as described [here](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_character_encodings).

Comment: `'utf-8'` is an alias for `'utf8'`

Comment: This is true for newer node-versions, yes.